# workfront(attask) UnsupportedOperationException API

Tags: c#, exception, attask

For anyone out there who might have a similar issue here's a very very bizard issue and how to solve it. So i was trying to update a custom form's field an i was getting the following error:

```
{"error":{"class":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException","message":"you must specify an action"}}
```

It was driving me crazy because i could update some of the forms data and some others i couldn't. Then i took a closer look at the names of the custom fields.
The ones that were giving me the error had the character # e.g. DE:Direct PTF #. So my REST request

**https://customerDomain.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/task?updates={'ID':'596b815900035a0c122d01555af1e095','DE:Direct PTF #':'some value'}&method=put&sessionID=c2898be87827e4e8696709ea192662193**

was failing while the following was not:

https://customerDomain.preview.workfront.com/attask/api/task?updates={'ID':'596b815900035a0c122d01555af1e095','DE:Customer Contract':'some value'}&method=put&sessionID=c2898be87827e4e8696709ea192662193

After a lot of trial an error i figured that the character # was the cause of the exception.So i tried %23 instead of #. Now i was getting a different error on the browser! I was about to give up when i thought to give it one more try through C# code and voila!It worked.I hope it will help a poor guy someday!

Comment: There's noting wrong with answering your own question, but you should write it in the form of a question and not as some kind of article. Write the answer in the Your Answer box below, and after a day or so you can select your own answer. Doing that will mark the question as answered in the UI.

Comment: Special characters tend to cause problems in custom field names for exactly the reason you discovered.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need try:

```
&method=post
```